# Heroku - "No web processes running" message, but server already started

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, heroku, mongoose

I'm facing the following issue with Heroku and my Node / Express / MongoDB app:

```
XXXX-05-10T22:56:41.782988+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-depths-03410.herokuapp.com request_id=d42d214e-051d-4ba9-842f-ad98cedaf4ab fwd="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I saw in a lot of posts that this error is related to the dyno scale, but I think this is not the case.

As you can see in the below logs, the app is running:

```
XXXX-05-10T22:41:56.098412+00:00 app[api.1]: yarn run v1.22.5
XXXX-05-10T22:41:56.253837+00:00 app[api.1]: $ node index.js
XXXX-05-10T22:41:57.849610+00:00 app[api.1]: server started on port 23804 (development)
```

but when I'm trying to access to my Heroku app: https://fast-depths-03410.herokuapp.com/ The only thing I can see is the message

> **Application error** check the logs..."

Regarding my app, I've tried the following things:

- I've scaled the dyno with `heroku ps:scale {myapp-name}=1`
- I've changed the listening port to use `process.env.PORT`
- I've added `EXPOSE $PORT` in my `Dockerfile`

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *something* running, but it's not a `web` process. Your log shows an *`api`* process:

```
XXXX-05-10T22:41:57.849610+00:00 app[api.1]: server started on port 23804 (development)
                                     ^^^
```

For non-Docker deploys, process types are defined by your `Procfile`, and [only `web` processes can receive traffic from the internet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type). In this scenario, change your `Procfile` from

```
api: some command
```

to

```
web: some command
```

and redeploy.

If you are using Docker, make sure to [use `web` for your `process-type` when you build and push your image](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s) and later when you release it, e.g.:

```
heroku container:push web
heroku container:release web
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not using a Procfile since it's not strictly needed, in regard of heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/370
I'll try changing the [image|slug] of heroku if that will solve the problem, the api process you can see there, is the name of the [image|slug] that I'm using when I push to heroku

Comment: Yep, good idea. One way or another, you need that to be a _`web`_ process.

Comment: Excellent! I've changed the [image|slug] name and it worked :) let me ask something, is this this way because I'm using free tier? Can I specify the name of the dyno as I want when I'm using a paid plan?

Comment: Great! I just updated my answer to include the Docker stuff. No, this has nothing to do with free or paid tiers. Heroku's process model specifies two "special" process types: [`web` processes must bind to `PORT` and they can receive traffic from the internet](heroku container:push <process-type>), and `release` processes run during your application's release phase. If you want to handle HTTP / HTTPS requests you must use a `web` process.